# How can I uninstall google-cloud-sdk ?

Tags: google-app-engine, terminal

I tried deleted Google Cloud AppEngine SDK from macbook, but I'm getting this

```
Last login: Thu Aug 11 14:12:18 on ttys002
-bash: /Users/Squirrel/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/Squirrel/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc: No such file or directory
```

Whenever I open a new terminal window.  Is there a way I can stop that from happening?

Comment: If you just uninstalled it and didn't log out/it try that 1st - your current env might still have knowledge of it from when you last logged in. If the issues persist check your ~/.bash* files and maybe the system's /etc/bash* files - probably one/more or them were modified when the SDK was installed to configure the its environment - look for references to the `/Users/Squirrel/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk` location.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  It was pretty obvious now, but I found it in `.bash_profile` and commented it out.

Comment: If you post, I'll green check u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the comment to an anwer...

Some SDK installations may modify system or user profiles to include proper setup of the SDK environment.

First thing to check, if the user didn't log out from the system since the uninstall, is if the errors are not just side effects of the current user session which already picked up the SDK environment. Logging out and back in should take care of such cases.

If the errors messages persist after logging out/in indicates that the removal of the installation did not clean up the system or user profiles modified at SDK installation, manual cleanup being required.

In your case the errors come from `bash`, so the files to check are either `/etc/bash*` or `~/.bash*` - look for `/Users/Squirrel/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk` - the now-removed SDK installation path mentioned in the messages.