# Fully un-installing google cloud sdk

Tags: ssh, terminal, google-cloud-platform

I tried to uninstall google cloud sdk from my computer a long time ago but when ever I login to terminal I get this message:

```
Last login: Sat Sep  9 12:40:05 on console
You have new mail.
-bash: /Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc: No such file or directory
ME:~ myshell$
```

I have [tried this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903433/how-can-i-uninstall-google-cloud-sdk) but the problem is I don't have a google cloud account anymore.

I also reach a dead end [on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854167/how-to-remove-gcloud-fully) as well b/c none of the files or folder seem to exist on my computer.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to edit your `.bashrc` and remove references to gloud-cloud-sdk look for lines like

```
source "$CLOUD_SDK/completion.bash.inc"
source "$CLOUD_SDK/paths.bash.inc"
```

Also, you may want to remove `~/.config/gcloud`

Comment: I tried to locate ~/.config/gcloud and it doesn't exist. Also, I am unable to access my .bashrc. I tried "open -t ~/.bashrc" and terminal just returns a ">"

Comment: Give a try to `vim ~/.bashrc `

Comment: this is what happens when I run that command. ME:~ myshell$ vim ~/.bashrc 

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
                                                                               
~                                                                                                                                                          
"~/.bashrc" 2L, 68C

Comment: Try then switching shells, type for example `csh` and once there edit/fix your `.basrc` or `.profile` etc

Comment: csh and open -t ~/.bashrc allowed me to edit .bashrc but nothing relative to gcloud was in there, only the same "
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting"